# Webservices and Server-Client Connection with Windows Phone in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services, windows-phone-8

I have a local test server on my pc on which I already filled a MySQL database. Now I would like to receive this data with my Windows Phone app and represent the data. 
Currently, I've made ​​it awkward. I have a PHP script on my server that represents the database. The app fetches the source code and parses it with the Html Agility Pack.

But this version is too complicated right? How can I do it better? I know something with webservices, but I do not know so much of them. Can someone explain to me in more detail? I heard from OData, but what should I do on my Apache Server and what should I do in my C# App? For the C# App there are examples. I feel so dumb because I really know nothing about web-services. And the most tutorials don't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement SOA (Service Oriented Architecture). You should have a look to WCF :
[WCF Tutorial for beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows)

The idea of web services is pretty simple. You store some services on a server (services = C# functions) and you consume them on your client (which is you windows phone app).

Comment: Ah, so the written C# examples on the internet are functions on the server. A webservice is the same as a GUI on the server? And how can I call the service with my app? Really thanks, you helped me!

Comment: To call you service, you'll have to create a "proxy". But you should read the tutorial, you'll have your answers. You also can have a look to this video tutorial : [tuto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlyND7b2-YA)

Comment: I got it. I write my WCF in C# and then I can do this in my /htdocs dir and call it with my app. I think it will go in this way. Thanks, the beginner tutorial is perfect to read!

Comment: I already found out that WCF don't work on apache :( Is there another chance with apache?

Comment: If you want to use WCF, IIS Server is required. I think that it's possible to host ASP.NET Web service on Apache but I never did that before.

Comment: With Windows Server 2012 I got an IIS Server? And whats with cgi on apache?